# Joda-Time Number of Days since Epoch

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a problem whereby the number of days since [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) returned by [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library changes depending the time of the date I entered. If I enter `2012-05-14 22:00:00` and   `2012-05-14 02:00:00` I would expect the same result since they are both on the same day. The following is my code.

```
        try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date1 = sdf.parse("2013-05-03 07:00:00");
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("2013-05-03 23:30:00");


        MutableDateTime epoch = new MutableDateTime();
        epoch.setDate(0); //Set to Epoch time
        System.out.println("Epoch: " + epoch);
        Days days1 = Days.daysBetween(epoch, new MutableDateTime(date1.getTime()));
        Days days2 = Days.daysBetween(epoch, new MutableDateTime(date2.getTime()));
        System.out.println("1) Days Since Epoch: " + days1.getDays());
        System.out.println("2) Days Since Epoch: " + days2.getDays());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
```

---

```
Epoch: 1970-01-01T11:09:00.414+01:00
1) Days Since Epoch: 15827
2) Days Since Epoch: 15828
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The results depend on your timezone. Remember that the start of the epoch is on 01-01-1970, 00:00:00 **GMT**. Depending on your timezone, 2012-05-14 22:00 and 2012-05-14 02:00 might be on different days when converted to GMT.

Answer (score 3):

OK found the problem (which was in front of my own eyes :)) ... the epoch I was getting was indeed starting from 1970-01-01 but not from the very first ms of that day.

I needed to add the following line to get it sorted:

```
epoch.setTime(0);
```

Comment: Just a note… For the general case of wanting to ignore time to focus on just the date, call the [withTimeAtStartOfDay()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()) method on [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html). Not sure if this applies to this issue; I did not test.